# Power Automate , Export Sharepoint Excel file to local

Tags: excel, sharepoint, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to set up a reoccurrence to export an excel file automatically to my local drive.

However I am running into problems with Get Items part as I cannot correctly link to the sharepoint excel.

Can anyone help with this?

**My flow**

[image]

**Getting url from the parent path:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As shown in the below screenshot, did you select the correct account under My connections?
[image]